# to read value from 2D vector

Tags: java

I am trying to read the values from a two dimensional vector.  if it is a one dimensional vector we can get the value like

```
 public static void getData(Vector content)
{
    contents = "";
    for(int i=0; i<content.size(); i++)
    {
        String string = "";
        String[] split = (String[])content.get(i);
}
```

I want to know is that possible to get the values in the same way for a 2D vector also.  if it is possible what can be the syntax .

Comment: What does your 2D vector look like?

Comment: its a vector that contains integer values

Answer (score 0):

```
vector v;
.... //vector gets stuff put in it
....
for(int x = 0; x < v.size(); x++)
{
  vector vv = v.get(x);
  for(int y = 0; y < vv.size(); y++)
  {
    System.out.println(vv.get(y));
  }
}
```

Haven't used java in a while but that seems about right to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try foreach loop

as like your code

```
public static void getData(Vector content)
    {
        contents = "";
        for(int i=0; i<content.size(); i++)
        {
            Vector  innerContent= content.get(i);
          for(int j=0; j<innerContent.size(); j++)
          {
            String string = "";
            String[] split = (String[])innerContent.get(j);
          }

    }
```